# How to select all documents in a mongodb AND remove a field

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Suppose I have a document defined in Mongoengine:

```
class User(document):
  username = StringField()
  password = StringField()
  login_history = ListField()
```

I have already created a couple of users with this "schema", now I want to drop the login_history field and update that to all users that have been created. How to do that in the mongo shell? And if possible, how to do that using MongoEngine?

Thanks guys!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409120/mongodb-removing-a-field-from-all-subdocuments-in-an-array-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `$unset` the field without specifying match criteria. So for Mongo Shell, it would be:

```
> db.user.update({}, {$unset: {login_history: true}}, {multi: true})
```

The critical part here to pay attention to is the `{multi: true}` option, without which you will end up with a single document updated.

**UPDATE**

For Mongoengine you have the same multi option as a keyword argument, see the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.update).